# Destringing in Python

Tags: python, input

I want to know if it is possible to destring things in Python.

I want to actually run the string returned by the input function. Is this possible in Python 3? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show in code what you are trying to do? It’s not clear what you mean by `destring`.

Comment: Is [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) or [`exec()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = input("What would you like to create?")
exec(s)
```

Run this code snippet with the input `x=3`. It will create the variable x with a value of 3! Obviously, this can be easily misused, so be careful with doing this in live production.

Comment: Is there something like this in JavaScript too?

Comment: @SafwanSamsudeen Yes, there is. It's called `eval()`, but many people advise against using it.

Comment: @GalaxyCat105, why? Security issues?

Comment: @SafwanSamsudeen That, and it's also ***very*** slow.